# i am geting this error when i use flickr api

Tags: python, flickr

```
import flickrapi
api_key = '1d3544994fb9b9a3a873a4e1c34fbe08'
api_password = '4b466122f9186bef'
flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)
favourites = flickrclient.favorites_getPublicList(user_id='132339441@N02')
photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='132339441@N02', per_page='10')
sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='132339441@N02')
for photo in favourites.photos[0].photo:
    print photo['title']
```

error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\web\joke.py", line 6, in
>   
>       photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='132339441@N02', per_page='10') NameError: name 'flickr' is not defined

Comment: Try adding adding a few more tags to your question (programming language is a must!) along with a better description of your problem and anything you've tried already. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this error is very clear in what's wrong, and you should have read it a little more carefully. It's literally saying that the variable `flickr` does not exist, which is true: nowhere in the code you're showing have you made a variable by that name. Time to fix that, and unask this question.

Comment: You've switched from using `flickrclient` to `flickr`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a typo because you are working with a variable called

```
flickrclient
```

And then you start using

```
flickr
```

I suspect some copy and paste ;-)